How do I expand a lightbox gallery on click so it overlays the entire screen?
I've got several galleries in my html, each identified by an individual div, in a larger wrapping div. I've managed to open them individually using this code but am wondering how to open these galleries so that they expand to the entire screen. Does anyone have any ideas?
function LaunchLightbox(num){
  lightboxcontainer=document.getElementsByClassName("slide-show_containers");
  lightboxcontainer[0].style.display="block";
    counter=0;
    slides=document.getElementsByClassName("image_slide" + num.toString());
    lightbox= document.getElementsByClassName("slide-show_" + num.toString() + "container");
    lightbox[0].style.display="block";
    slides[counter].style.display="block";
    totalimages=slides.length;
    console.log(slides);
    console.log(totalimages);
}

function CloseLightbox(num){
  HideImages()
  lightbox = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-show_" + num.toString() + "container");
  lightbox[0].style.display="none";
  lightboxcontainer=document.getElementsByClassName("slide-show_containers");
  lightboxcontainer[0].style.display="none";

I have tried to ascertain how to do this but have so far hit a brick wall

Don't use global variables. Avoid using styles in JS if all you need is a single .is-open in CSS. To answer your question (which seems like a CSS one) use .is-open { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; pointer-events: auto;} and the opposite styles as default. Also width: 100dvw; and height: 100dvh;  would be needed to make it cover the entire viewport. Avoid using querySelectors to match the opened ones, instead use a variable or a static class property to store a Set of initialized Lightboxes instances.

HideImages if for what exactly? Why hide images if all you need is to close the active Lightbox? OK, so, CSS classes, toggle them using Element.classList.toggle("is-open")

Also, this line lightboxcontainer[0].style.display="block"; seems more like a bug than a feature since it restricts you from potentially using multiple lightboxes in a single document.
